# Radio button doesn't set as checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I making some test - http://magora-systems-test.esy.es/ , and one of the task make Radio Buttons stilization by JavaScript(jQuery). I remaking construktion again and again but always one problem: JS successfully set input radio button attribute as checked="checked" by clicking the stylized clone , but it doesn't set as chosen indeed, and required attribute talkink the same. I doen't understand WHY?

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="userAge">
        <div class="fieldName">
            Возраст:
        </div>
        <div class="overflow">
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="seventeen" title="Выберите если вы младше 17" required>
            <label for="seventeen">17 и младше</label>
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="eighteen" title="Выберите если вы старше 18" required>
            <label for="eighteen">18 и старше</label>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

**JS:**

```
;(function($) {
    // Расширяем набор элементов jQuery новым плагином.
    $.fn.sexyElement = function() {

        // Запуск для всех инициализаций на странице.
        $(this).each(function() {
            var element = $(this);

            // RADIO
            else if (element.is(':radio')) {

                // Для всех существующих радио кнопок.
                element.each(function() {

                        // Создание и обработка радио кнопок.
                        var createRadio = function(){
                            var sexyRadio = '<div class="radio" title="' + element.attr('title') + '">\
                                                <div class="dot">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>';
                            element.before(sexyRadio);
                        }

                        // Запуск функции.
                        createRadio();
                });

                // Определяем основные элементы.
                var commonParent = element.parents().eq(0),
                    buttons = commonParent.find(':radio');

                // Обработка щелчка мыши.
                $('.radio').click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('checked').siblings().removeClass('checked');
                    buttons.attr('checked', false);
                    $(this).next(':radio').attr('checked', true);
                    buttons.change();
                });
            }
            // END RADIO

            // В противном случае.
            else {
                alert('Пожайлуста убедитесь, что выбранный вами элемент является select или radio');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Launch plugin:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':radio').sexyElement();
});
```

PS: Sorry some titles on Russian language. And label JS code do not written yet.

Comment: Hello there are 2 radio buttons in EACH radio button , one is Blue ,other is gray.What is expected ?

Comment: checked="checked" is working properly.Whats issue

Comment: _What is expected ?_ - Yes, this is expected. This is for testing. Later it will be hidden by css.

Comment: Please tell me are you comfortable with English? I asked What do u expect?

Comment: Yes i'm, but sometimes, i have to using google translater. Sorry, I'm not really understand what you mean about expect?

Comment: I think The Customized Radio button u used ,does not Click actual Radio button

Comment: Which Javascript Plugin u have used for Customized radio button?

Comment: I create this plugin by myself. You can see this code and initialization of this plugin upper. CSS you can see in a browser.

Comment: Everything is working, but i not understand why dot not appear in the real input-radio-button.

Comment: Why dont u use Readymade Radio buttons ,and then u can apply your own style . http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/   .Check The plugin works fine .U just change little css

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know why but this bug was SOLVED by puting input radio button to his label.

**Before:**

```
<fieldset class="userAge">
        <div class="fieldName">
            Возраст:
        </div>
        <div class="overflow">
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="seventeen" title="Выберите если вы младше 17" required>
            <label for="seventeen">17 и младше</label>
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="eighteen" title="Выберите если вы старше 18" required>
            <label for="eighteen">18 и старше</label>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

**After:**

```
<fieldset class="userAge">
    <div class="fieldName">
        Возраст:
    </div>
    <div class="overflow">
        <label for="seventeen">
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="seventeen" title="Выберите если вы младше 17" required>
            17 и младше
        </label>
        <label for="eighteen">
            <input type="radio" name="userAge" id="eighteen" title="Выберите если вы старше 18" required>
            18 и старше
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Anyway any ideas why?